# Proving that a sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $q$, $x$, $y$ be real numbers and $0$$\leq$$q$$<$$1$.

Define a sequence ($a_{n}$) by $a_{1}$:=$y$ and $a_{n+1}$:=$q$($a_{n}$+$x$) for all $n$$\geq$$1$.

Does ($a_{n}$) converge?

So if $q$ is 0 the sequence definitely converges to 0. Otherwise, does the sequence converge? I was thinking of splitting it into cases, for example if x=y, x>y, x

Comment: So if $q$ is 0 the sequence definitely converges to 0. Otherwise, does the sequence converge? I was thinking of splitting it into cases, for example if x=y, x>y, x<y and seeing if consecutive terms are either increasing or decreasing. Should I use induction to show this? Is this the right approach?

Comment: What I wrote in previous comment was cut off in original question

Comment: What have you tried?  The case $y=0$ seems like a natural start.  Can you write the sequence out in that case?

Comment: 0, qx, q$x^{2}$+qx, ... It is increasing if x is positive and decreasing if negative?

Comment: Correct, if x is positive.  Alternating if x is negative.  Hard to tell much from "increasing" or "decreasing" though.

Comment: The case where y is 0, is that considered a subsequence? If I show that a subsequence converges, is that enough?

Comment: Oh, no.  Not at all.  It's just a practice case to work through.  As a rule, if a problem is too messy to work with, try special cases that are simpler.  That often generates good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If
$a_{n+1}=q(a_n+x) 
$,
then
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{q}=a_n+x 
$
or,
dividing by
$q^n$,
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{q^{n+1}}=\frac{a_n}{q^n}+\frac{x}{q^n} 
$.

Let $b_n
=\frac{a_n}{q^n}
$.
Then
$b_{n+1}
=b_n+\frac{x}{q^n}
$
or
$b_{n+1}-b_n
=\frac{x}{q^n}
$.

Summing from $n=1$ to $m-1$,
$b_m-b_1
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{x}{q^n}
=x \frac{\frac1{q^m}-\frac1{q}}{\frac1{q}-1}
=\frac{x}{q^m} \frac{1-q^{m-1}}{\frac1{q}-1}
$.

Since
$b_1 = \frac{y}{q}$,
$\frac{a_m}{q^m}
=\frac{y}{q}+\frac{x}{q^m} \frac{1-q^{m-1}}{\frac1{q}-1}
$
or
$a_m
=yq^{m-1}+x\frac{1-q^{m-1}}{\frac1{q}-1}
$.

Since
$q^m \to 0$,
$a_m
\to \frac{x}{1/q-1}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Write out the first few terms.  We have:  $$a_1=y$$ $$a_2=q(y+x)=qy+qx$$
$$a_3=q(qy+qx+x)=q^2y+q^2x+qx$$ $$a_4=q(q^2y+q^2x+qx+x)=q^3y+q^3x+q^2x+qx$$
And so on.

As n grows we see that the term in y goes to $0$ (it is $q^{n-1}y$).  The terms in x are a geometric series which we can easily sum to deduce that the sequence converges to $$\frac {qx}{1-q}$$

Comment: Oh okay, so supposing I wanted to write out a proof, would I just have to show that as n increases the sequence becomes $\frac{qx}{1-q}$?

Comment: To write out a proof carefully you should establish a simple form for $a_n$. From the above it appears to be $a_n=q^{n-1}y+\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1}q^ix$, which is true, but you should prove it.  Then you should prove (or quote a theorem) which lets you evaluate this sum as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  Neither proof is difficult, but both are worth writing out.